# Retrieve Data from Ajax Get Type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my question its "simple".
I have this function Ajax :

> ```
> function preencherLinhaProduto(obj) {
>     $.ajax({type: "POST",
>         url: '/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/pesquisarLinhaProduto',
>         async: false,
>         data: {
>             cd_cpl_tamanho: obj
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

And I want to take the ID from "cd_cpl_tamanho" that recieves "obj" on this another function:

> ```
> public function pesquisarLinhaProduto(){
>     $this->autoRender = false;
>     $this->loadModel('ProcuraProdutoPedOnline');
>     // Consultando pelo que o usuÃ¡rio estÃ¡ digitando
>     //$produto = $this->$_REQUEST['cd_cpl_tamanho'];
>     //$produto = $this->request->params['obj'];
>     echo($produto);
>     $linhas = $this->ProcuraProdutoPedOnline->find('all', array(
>             'fields' => array('cd_linha', 'ds_linha'),
>             'conditions' => array(
>                     'cd_cpl_tamanho' => "$produto"
>             )
>     ));
> ```

And I don't know how to do... I want to make a search on DB where cd_cpl_tamanho recieves $produto that contains the ID of function Ajax.

Sorry for my Bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Well, searching and trying I found myself the answer..

The global variable : $_REQUEST['parent']; solved my problem.